# Vue router-link params

Tags: laravel, routes, vue.js

I have a problem with my router-link :to. My router-link doesn't render my template. here is my web routing, routes.js and vue template. I want to go after clik on img product to: 'product/1234' but it redirect me only 'product'. Where is my mistake?
Web:

```
     Route::get('/product/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
```

routes.js:

```
 {
        path: '/product/:id',
        name: 'ProductIndex',
        component: ProductIndex
    }
```

and Vue template:

```
 <div class="product" v-for="product in products">
            <router-link class="product-image" :to="{ path: 'product', params: { id: product.id}}">
                <img src="/static/shop/products/shoe-example.png"/>
            </router-link>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you realize that `vue-router` and the Laravel routing system are two separate things, right?

Comment: What do you have inside method show in ProductController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are linking to the path, try changing it to the name of your route:

```
<router-link class="product-image" :to="{ name: 'ProductIndex', params: { id: product.id}}">
      <img src="/static/shop/products/shoe-example.png"/>
</router-link>
```